# Constant Contact C# Wrapper - Add Contact to a List

Tags: c#

I am trying to add contacts to a list using the c# wrapper. My problem is that I can successfully add to a list, if I am adding the contact for the first time. However, If i delete the contact through the Constant Contact Interface and try adding the contact again from my asp.net C# function, it fails.

I did some research and I did understand that:
1) I first need to check if the contacts email address exists
2) Then, update or post accordingly.

Any help/advice with the above is appreciated. I have spent a lot of time trying to get this work and have had no luck.

Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConstantContactBO.Contact c = new ConstantContactBO.Contact();

        AuthenticationData authdata = new AuthenticationData();
        authdata.Username = "";
        authdata.Password = "";
        authdata.ApiKey = "";

        c.EmailAddress = "joe@a.com";

        ContactOptInList theList = new ContactOptInList();
        c.OptInSource = ContactOptSource.ActionByContact;
        theList.ContactList = new ContactList("39");
        c.ContactLists.Add(theList);

        ConstantContactUtility.Utility.CreateNewContact(authdata, c);
```

}

I would like to be able to check if an email exists or not and then update or add a contact to the list.

Comment: This code is not describing your problem enough. Where is the deleting part and other parts that would make more sense?

Comment: Well I did not add any code for deleting it. I did it through the "Constant Contact's" Interface. I would like to be able to check if the contact exists and then update or add the contact to the list accordingly. My trouble is with checking if the contact exists in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here https://github.com/constantcontact/Constant-Contact-Dot-Net-ASP-Contact-Forms/blob/master/Web/UploadContactForm/AddContactSmallForm.aspx.cs you can find beatiful sample for the code you are looking for, I believe. You can find even more docs here http://developer.constantcontact.com/ if identified product you are using correctly.

```
    string nextChunkId;
    IList<Contact> list = Utility.SearchContactByEmail(AuthenticationData, emailAddress, out nextChunkId);
    if (list.Count == 0)
    {
        // create new Contact
        Contact contact = GetContactInformation();

        Utility.CreateNewContact(AuthenticationData, contact);
        Response.Redirect("~/AddContactConfirmation.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ConstantException(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            "Email address \"{0}\" is already a contact", txtEmail.Text.Trim()));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help. The link was absolutely useful!

Answer (score 0):

Try this using Lambda expression

```
int count = c.ContactLists.Count(cc => cc.EmailAddress == "joe@a.com");
if(count == 0) //does not exist
{
   //add this contact
}
else
{

}
```